# jquery-autocomplete how to trigger the “autocomplete” event with send the value (the request value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, triggers, jquery-autocomplete

I want to trigger the “autocomplete” event from the sorce, and to send the value to set in the textBox.

I want it will be like a user typing the value and trigger the autocomplete,
I tried to look alot but all the examples I found didn't send the value,
and I need to send the value!!

This example dosn't help me, Because I need the request (like someone type it)

```
$("#CompanyList").autocomplete({
  source : yourSource,
  change : yourChangeHandler
});

$("#CompanyList").data("autocomplete")._trigger("change");
```

I hope you Understand me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand (I'm not sure).

You have to go costum:

Use:

```
 $('.input_text_forms').keyup(function(event){ });
```

That fires:

```
 var data = $('#lang_pass_threw').val();
 $.post('auto_fill.php', { data: data }, function(response) {  });
```

When the request is returned:

```
  var arr = string.split("");
```

Now call to a Timeout function and set the result as the value...

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjJrj/)

This example is a bit buggy, there is a cursor position to set.. and a backspace event to undo the autocomplete etc, let me know if its what you need and i'll tune this script a bit.